# Sorting table into buckets without overlapping timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a table representing a series of events:

```sql
CREATE TABLE events (
    id UUID,
    starttime timestamp,
    endtime timestamp,
    data varchar
);
```

and I am attempting to sort it into a series of N buckets where all the events in a bucket are not overlapping in time, such that if there's a collision in bucket 0 the event is attempted to be placed in bucket 1 and so on to bucket N, or placed in an "overflow" bucket if there is no space for the event without colliding.

For example, with N=2:

| 0 | 1 | overflow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11:55-12:20 | 12:00-12:05 | 12:05-12:20 |
| 12:25-12:30 | 12:05-12:10 |  |

So because both bucket 0 and 1 are occupied during 12:05-12:20, this event is not inserted into either.

Is there a straightforward way of accomplishing this?

Comment: This looks like [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) could be useful here.

Comment: does it definitely have to be done in SQL? not saying it isn't possible, but it would be a whole lot simpler to query up the list of events, then iterate through them with a procedural language like JS or Python to bucket the events.

Comment: It's not pretty, but here's what I came up with: https://pastebin.com/eCqTBq2j (mostly as practice, haven't written pgsql in 5ever. Don't judge me!)